Old cartoon with titans
I'm looking for a cartoon that I remember from when I was a kid. I think it was from like '96-98ish. The series takes place in some small village.
This boy finds something like a capsule (I remember it being like those plastic coins you could buy and play as a game, Caps they were called). When he spins it a titan spawns, like a vulcano titan, and there are more coins/capsules like this.
I remember the main character to be a young boy. On the first episode he ran through a rice field or something because he is late. He is going to meet with his uncle I think, and on the way to his uncle he trips and finds the token/cap.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

A Cartoon with titans being summoned reminds me of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntik:Secrets%26_Seekers, but that's not a village and the summon method is different.

Thank you for the information regarding the cartoon, I had a look at Huntik, unfortunately it's not the cartoon I am looking for but thank you so much anyway!

Do you know the country of origin? The fact that the character is running through the ricefield makes the show sound like it is Asian, as few western shows have settings involving them.

Pretty sure it's Legend of the Hawaiian Slammers, it was only a single pilot episode, and I don't know if it ever aired on tv, but it involved a kid finding a cap embedded in volcanic rock that fell into a wheat field, and he could use it to summon a volcano titan.
